# Api de laravel me pide un parametro "api_token"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.8
El punto es que quiero enviar el token por header con axios a la api que tengo con laravel. De hecho el `app.js` ya le aplica el token con el metadato en el header.

El problema surge porque la api me pide un `api_token` en lugar de `_token` o `X-CSRF-TOKEN` en el header...

he intentado muchas maneras, hasta con postman lo envie con Bearer...

Uso los middlewares por defecto que trae laravel, no he creado nada nuevo... ya no se que archivo tocar.

este es el request header que arroja el navegador:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InQ0M3Bna2VYbFcxS1cwV1pLWTFUWFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoib3BJRmY1NDA5amZnRWc3dHNDV0M5NStXeEl3K1BxNlwvdFE4NWhsOXR2RTJGY2k5aEkxNTNVYnE5amUrZWhTcHAiLCJtYWMiOiI2NzgxZDMwZWU2YjIxNjU5Y2I3NzM0MDRmMTYzZjVlOGY5YTRlZDk4YmE3OTJjNGQ1MDY1ZWVjYzBlM2M1NWIwIn0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkxnT0pRc1hQNlFwU3duQ0Q3MlhrMlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMERqSHd3emh5Z2xweThibTI3VFVDRU1nVm1zYVVlcnFCUHJpUnB2VUZZY2xIRUNkT0R6SllCSTBSSlBqTzFJdSIsIm1hYyI6IjNlOWFmZjc5YTkxODliNjRlOTMyMWEzYTE4NzUxZDJkNTQzMDRlYWZjMzBkODFlYjJjN2U5YzYxNmVkNWY0MzMifQ%3D%3D
Host: facturador-pro.local
Referer: http://facturador-pro.local/memberships
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN: Q7Xh32zIPFg932ElU6wjkZmT1dGgpNvFEWzIlrPh
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6InQ0M3Bna2VYbFcxS1cwV1pLWTFUWFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoib3BJRmY1NDA5amZnRWc3dHNDV0M5NStXeEl3K1BxNlwvdFE4NWhsOXR2RTJGY2k5aEkxNTNVYnE5amUrZWhTcHAiLCJtYWMiOiI2NzgxZDMwZWU2YjIxNjU5Y2I3NzM0MDRmMTYzZjVlOGY5YTRlZDk4YmE3OTJjNGQ1MDY1ZWVjYzBlM2M1NWIwIn0=
```

Lo unico que he modificado es el middleware `Authenticate.php`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest() && $guard == 'api') {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest() && $guard == 'web') {
        return route('login');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué mensaje de error aparece?

Comment: @Shaz me sale el mensaje de "Unauthorized", he puesto el metodo handle del middleware en la pregunta.

Comment: si envio el token con parametro api_token funciona bien, pero lo quiero enviar por header

Comment: seguiste los pasos de la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#configuration). Tienes que configuralo (agregar un campo en la tabla users) y generar los tokens para cada usuario.

Comment: Básicamente mi pregunta es, por que me pide un api_token como parametro si ese valor no lo pide ningun middleware

Comment: la ruta a la que quieres acceder debe estar dentro del middleware auth:api. Haz una ruta así `Route::get('/', [function() { return 'hola, yo soy la api'; }]);` y ponla arriba de todo en el archivo `routes/api.php`. Luego con el navegador o postman accede a `http://tu-dominio/api` y ve si responde

Comment: Sin esta dentro de auth:api.. y si responde

Comment: Ok. Entonces, tienes dos opciones, o quitas la ruta del middleware y la dejas pública (como el ejemplo de 'hola yo soy la api'), o configuras la autenticación de la api siguiendo la documentación de laravel o algún tutorial como [este que usa passport](https://medium.com/@cvallejo/sistema-de-autenticaci%C3%B3n-api-rest-con-laravel-5-6-240be1f3fc7d) que es lo que recomiendan en la misma documentación.